# EC2 Instance Available Bandwidth?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bandwidth

Is there any way to determine what should be your available bandwidth on EC2? Documentation seems to indicate that it should be based on your instance size, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding any specific numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is based on your instance size and the only #'s I could find were for XL instances.  Supposedly, they should get 300-350 Mbps.

Comment: Thanks Dave, do you happen have a link to where they say 300-350mbps for XL?

Comment: My experience with EC2 is only via the Wowza Media Server.  I've seen bandwidth #'s all over their forums: http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums